# ngStorage Array Gets Reset on Load

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ng-storage

I'm using ngStorage and I declare a new array that I'm going to push objects to. However, whenever the page reloads the array gets reset.

Is there a way to re-write this so that I can still declare the new empty array and then push objects to the array in Local Storage without it being reset everytime the page loads?

```
  var myFaves = [];
  $scope.myFaves = myFaves; 
  $localStorage.myFaves = myFaves; 

  $scope.addFave = function(object){
    $localStorage.myFaves.push(object);
    console.log("$localStorage.myFaves", $localStorage.myFaves);
  }
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bTtjFmh01V3NrVknmMkU?p=preview)

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if the array exists before you set it to an empty array. That way you won't overwrite any previous values.

```
if ($localStorage.myFaves === undefined) {
  $localStorage.myFaves = [];
}
```